LogQL sum by __line__
I use opentelemetry to send logs to Loki, and thus I get very nicely formatted log entries that are easy to query on:

Now I want to get some statistics out of the logs about login activity:
sum by(__line__) (
  count_over_time({} | scope_name = "UserAuthenticator" | label_format level=detected_level [5m])
)

The problem is by(__line__) does not work. Nor does __line, line, log, body, message. What is the magic keyword to group by the log text template?

IIRC, __line__ being built-in (pseudo?)label is dropped by any aggregation. If you want to preserve it you need to add a normal label and use it: label_format line=`{__line__}` 

@markalex Make it an answer, so I can mark it as so. Thanks

I will not. But please feel free to post an answer yourself, after you tested my suggestion in situ (I'm pretty sure i missed second set of curly braces)

As @markalex wrote, we can create a new label using the label_format, and then sum by that:
sum by(line) (
  count_over_time({}
   | scope_name = "UserAuthenticator"
   | label_format level=detected_level
   | label_format line=`{{__line__}}`
  [5m])
)

